# snakemake built-in md5sum function

Tags: python, snakemake

Under the header "Ensuring output file properties like non-emptyness or checksum compliance" of the `snakemake` [tutorial rule section][1] the following is stated:

```
It is possible to annotate certain additional criteria for output files to be ensured after they have been generated successfully. For example, this can be used to check for output files to be non-empty, or to compare them against a given sha256 checksum. If this functionality is used, Snakemake will check such annotated files before considering a job to be successful. Non-emptyness can be checked as follows:

> rule NAME:
>     output:
>         ensure("test.txt", non_empty=True)
>     shell:
>         "somecommand {output}"

Above, the output file test.txt is marked as non-empty. If the command somecommand happens to generate an empty output, the job will fail with an error listing the unexpected empty file.

A sha256 checksum can be compared as follows:

my_checksum = "u98a9cjsd98saud090923ßkpoasköf9ß32"

> rule NAME:
>     output:
>         ensure("test.txt", sha256=my_checksum)
>     shell:
>         "somecommand {output}"

Is it possible to change sha256 to md5sum? The reason is that I frequently need to download data that comes with md5sums instead of sha256.


 [SnakeMake Official Documentation][1]


  [1]: https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#ensuring-output-file-properties-like-non-emptyness-or-checksum-compliance
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now there is no built-in support for alternative checksum functions, see this [feature proposal on GitHub](https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/issues/1972).

Answer (score 0):

Is a dedicated Snakemake function necessary? I may be missing something here but this is what I would do:

```
rule one:
    output: ...
    params:
        expected_md5='foobarspam'
    shell:
        r"""
        curl ... > {output}
        md5sum {output} | cut -f 1 -d ' ' | grep -w '{params.expected_md5}'
        """
```

Not tested, but it should work because `grep` returns non-zero exit code if there is no match. One could achieve the same using `awk` if you want more control.